# Which is the WordPress table relationship between wp_terms and wp_termmeta?

Tags: wordpress

I've been reviewing the WordPress database structure and wondered whether is there an error in one of the depicted relationships.

According to the schema published on https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description it seems that one wp_termmeta can have many wp_terms; however it seems logical to me to be the other way around. Such as the case with posts or users, i.e. one wp_post can have many wp_postmeta and one wp_user can have many wp_usermeta.

Any thoughts about this? Is this a mistake in the Codex?

Answer (score 0):

> it seems that one wp_termmeta can have many wp_terms

I don't read it this way. The term_meta functions were added in WP 4.4, so it's still relatively new and maybe lacking a bit on the documentation. I believe it's an attempt to include the developers who've used meta for CPT's (and everything else) for a long time now. They're just custom fields added to terms, which are now officially supported by WP core.

It might be better to look at it from a [functional standpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta).

The columns for wp_termmeta are:

```
meta_id (unique)
term_id (foreign key)
key (name)
value
```

Each entry can't have a range as its term_id, it can only be a single value that corresponds to the term_id found in the wp_terms table. So each term_id can have many entries in wp_termmeta, but not the other way around.